# mod_rewrite - neewd to make an exception for addresses that contain a certain word

Tags: exception, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

HI, I have a mod_rewrite in my .htaccess file that is reformatting address. I already have one exception that will keep .cfg files free from the rewrite, I'm trying to do that same with .html files that contain the word "client" but have had no luck trying a number of different approaches. I'm out of my depths with .htaccess stuff unfortunately.

Here is the file currently:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule \.cfg$ - [L]
RewriteRule client - [L]


RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-d
RewriteRule  .* index.php 

</IfModule>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change the client line to:

```
RewriteRule client(.*?)\.html - [L,NC]
```